# Restore file with data cocoa?

Tags: file, cocoa, encryption

How can I restore a file with certain data. If a user enters a file in which he wants the data to be restored with, and that file is not there, it should be created with *that* data. This is all part of an encryption tool. So say I, the user, selects a file, and encrypts it. So I have my encrypted data. But now I need to move this encrypted data to a file, so that the user can take the file that contains the encrypted data, to decrypt, so that he gets his original file provided he entered the correct key.

Hopefully that was clear enough. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, not at all clear.  "Restore" generally means "putting it back the way it was".  Do you actually mean you want to write the new (encrypted) data to a new file?

Comment: I apologize if it was not clear. Yes what I mean is I want to write the new encrypted data to a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using NSHomeDirectory instead of hardcoding the path. Thanks though for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSFileManager to get (and possiby create) the file path for the data, then writeToFile: methods.  Something like this:

```
- (void) saveCriteriaToFile: (NSArray *) criteria
{       
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *supportDir = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"StokerX"];

NSString *saveFilePath = [supportDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: kSavedNotificationsFile];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: saveFilePath] == NO)
{
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: supportDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
}

[criteria writeToFile:saveFilePath atomically:YES];
}
```

This one is writing an NSArray object to a pilist, but you do it almost the same with an NSData object.

Comment: `writeToFile:atomically:` is a method of the NSArray (or NSData or whatever) object, not the NSFileManager object. The NSFileManager method is `createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:`.